# checkbox onclick event loads as if checked

Tags: javascript, html

When I load the page both forms are displayed. If I check and then uncheck "add" the second form disappears. How do I make this page load with form 2 hidden on load?

```
<html>
<title>Car Service</title>
<strong>Car Service:</strong><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="accountsearch" name="accountsearch" value="Select Customer" onclick="window.open('selectaccount.php');"><br><br>
<form name="newservicesetup" id="newservicesetup" action="" method="post">
    <select name="ordertype" id="ordertype">
        <option>(Select Service)</option>
        <option value="Service">Service</option>
        <option value="ServiceHardware">Service w/ Hardware</option>            
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="qty1" id="qty1" value="Quantity" size="5" onclick="this.value=''">
    <input type="checkbox" id="add" value="0" name="add" onclick="
        if (this.checked) {
            document.getElementById('newservicesetup1').style.display='inline';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('newservicesetup1').style.display='none'; } return true;" >
</form>
<form name="newservicesetup1" id="newservicesetup1" action="" method="post">
    <select name="ordertype1" id="ordertype1">
        <option>(Select Service)</option>
        <option value="Service">Service</option>
        <option value="ServiceHardware">Service w/ Hardware</option>            
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="qty2" id="qty2" value="Quantity" size="5" onclick="this.value=''">
</form>
<br>
    XX: <input type="file" name="sfa" id="sfa">
    AA1: <input type="file" name="pbxws" id="pbxws"><br>    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="next" id="next" value="Next">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the second forms css class to hidden or something like that and then define .hidden in your css to be display:none. Or put style='display:none' t ostart with on the second form

Answer (score 0):

Change your second form tag to read this....

```
<form name="newservicesetup1" id="newservicesetup1" action="" method="post" style="display:none;">
```